# How to get input data from an external excel file into a feature file in cucumber (JAVA)...?

Tags: java, excel, cucumber, gherkin

Is there a way to get input data from an excel file in gherkin into a feature file (Cucumber) specially in JAVA...?
For .Net there is a way to specify the location of the excel file in the feature file using @source tag.
Is there any similar way for JAVA as well...?

For an example,

Feature: User provides details to sign in

Scenario Outline: Provide details

```
Given user navigates to 'https://world.com/signin'

And user waits for short

And user fills 'first_name' with '<Firstname>'

And user waits for short

And user fills 'email' with '<Email>'
```

How to provide the Firstname and Email from the excel file in feature file (JAVA)...?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there is no way to out of the box read Excel files from Cucumber-JVM.

I would probably see if I could do one of these:

- Extract that data to the scenario
- Implement reading the Excel file in the helper method that the step delegates to

The first option assumes that you don't have more than a handful of addresses. If you have that, then this might be a candidate for something else than Cucumber. Say JUnit instead.

If you have many addresses, then I would implement the extraction in the step helper if you really must use Cucumber as a testing tool.